# MARIADB: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Im trying to create 3 different tables in mariadb. I am using the exact same code I used in my localhost and it worked.

The tables name are: location, artist and murals.

I first create the location table, then I create the artist table and finally I try create the murals table because this is where my foreign keys will be, but I keep getting the following error:

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `KOMA`.`murals` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

## Creating Location Table

```sql
Create TABLE location(
l_id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
country varchar(255),
city varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
address varchar(255),
a_number int(10),
zipcode int(5)
);
```

## Creating artist Table

```sql
Create TABLE artist(
a_id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL );
```

## Creating murals Table

```sql
CREATE table murals (
m_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
imageurl varchar(255) NOT NULL,
about varchar(255) NOT NULL,
year INT(4),
a_id INT(11),
l_id INT(11),
FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES artist,
FOREIGN KEY (l_id) REFERENCES location
);
```

I would like to be able to create the last table with my foreign keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a foreign key, you need to point to the "parent" table *and* the referenced column; MySQL doesn't assume that the column has the same name.

```
CREATE TABLE `murals` (
    `m_id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    `imageurl` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `about` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `year` INT(4),
    `a_id` INT(11),
    `l_id` INT(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `artist`(`a_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`l_id`) REFERENCES `location`(`l_id`)
);
```

Comment: Also, are the `` required always in mariadb?

Comment: No problem! The backticks aren't required, but they allow you to use keywords for column names (e.g. defining a column name as comment will give you an error, but defining it as \`comment\` will allow for it). I use them generally just for communicating that intent and to make sure that I know what's a column and what's a string